# Обработка в асинхронной функции цикла, затем обработка вложенной в цикл функции тоже количество итераций

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть цикл (см. ниже //цикл перебора данных). В цикл вставлена обработка класса по событию. Это обработка класса $('.picttime') больше нигде не работает. Асинхронные функции цепляются одна за другую чтобы не потерять данные подгружаемые с баз (data3, data4). Сначала цикл отрабатывает прорисовку динамической таблицы , НО затем обработка класса повторяется равное количество итераций. Нужно чтобы обработка класса выполнялась один раз после выполнения цикла. у меня оказалось удачным выполнение цикла, а затем функции. Но вот хотелось чтобы функция выполнилась один раз. За пределами цикла функция не работает, внутри цикла в функции прерывание цикла делал - прерывается выполнение цикла. Асинхронность это что-то нечто. Чтобы передать результаты из одной функции в другую у меня все асинхронные функции сложены одна в другую как матрешка. Все функции у меня это пополнение данных из баз (.load). Ну вот как-то так. Второй вопрос: может еще подскажите как завершив одну асинхронную функцию получить из неё данные и внести их в другую функцию. Чтобы получалась не матрешка а последовательность. Я понимаю что матрешка это хорошая экономия времени при асинхронной обработке, но при десятикратном вложении когда-то нужно прервать нарастающий ком.

```
$("#...").load('....php',{},function(data3){    // получаем данные с базы №1
    for(i=0; i < j; i++)  //цикл перебора данных
    {
        $("#...").load('....php',{}, function(data4){    // получаем данные с базы №2
            ...
            for(var z=1; z<(h4-h1+n); z++)   //цикл обработки и создания таблицы
            {                                                                               
                timeSotr = timeSotr + "<td><table id='tabl_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"' name=='tabl_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"' class='minifont'><tr>"+  
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_10' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_10' value='.' class='but picktime'></td>"+ 
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_20' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_20' value='.' class='but picktime'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_30' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_30' value='.' class='but picktime'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_40' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_40' value='.' class='but picktime'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_50' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_50' value='.' class='but picktime'></td>"+
                "<td><input type='button' id='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_60' name='_lg_"+lgUs+"_row_"+np+"_h_"+(h1+z-1)+"_m_60' value='.' class='but picktime'></td></tr></table></td>";
            }   
            timeSotr = timeSotr + "</tr></table>";  
            $('#t'+i+'n3').html(timeSotr);


            $('.picktime').click(function(){    //класс обработки, должен выполняться один раз

            });
        });
    }  
});
```

Comment: Тот случай, когда пора изучать [обещания (Promises)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: `$('body').one('click', '.picktime', function(){});` вне цикла

Comment: спасибо, занялся изучением, раньше не пользовался.

Comment: br3t не получилось. На первой итерации цикла обработчик работает на второй нет. Обработчик перенес сразу за цикл.

Comment: br3t, разобрался. Да действительно работает только один раз. Т.е. если использовать обработку события еще раз уже не получается. Имелось ввиду что при обработке функция обработчика выполнялась столько раз сколько итераций в цикле. Теперь выполняется однажды. Хотелось бы чтобы при повторном нажатии обработчик выполнялся еще раз.

Comment: разобрался и с этим. Достаточно поменять ".one" на ".on"